# TypeScript: Define a type by inferring a Function's Argument Types

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

Is there any possibility to describe a type that gets inferred by a function's parameters? I need something like this:

```js
// some fn I have no control over its params
function someFn(a: string, b?: number, c?: any): any { /* ... */ }

// my wanted type that describes the args as object-records:
const result: MyType<typeof someFn> = {
 a: 'str',
 b: 42,
 c: null
};
```

I have no control over the signature of the functions' parameters, so converting it into `someFn(args: SomeFnArgs)` and `MyType<SomeFnArgs>` is not an option.

I don't know if it is even possible to describe the type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, although not quite in that way. The names of parameters are lost when typing function signatures. The arguments type for `someFn` in your example is `[string, number?, any]` (although that example is not quite valid, since non-optional parameters may not appear after optional parameters.

You can get this type with this ([playground](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/PTAEBcE8AcFNQAoEMBOSC2tyxQZwDwAqosAHtgHYAmuoAYgK4UDG4AlgPYUB8oAvKGJlKNUAAoAdFNQBzXAC5QbCgDMcoAEoBKfryQVIoAPybQiirABuOANwAoEKAASHAO5LwAclpt00ADawmBTYVAA0iKgYWDg+tEigAEYMbP7gALTKEDCwEnZ2KkysnBSguByYdBRiSIq44CjKMhGJRuYM6Ik4EcxtoPqQWooDoADeoMAAVKBSEqCTYAC++VBwggAM-JFomNh4+KuwHCplFbBV3DYTYIcbWwDa9Y0UzeIUHV0ooAA+oExUsBUylgVC0RgiAyMAF18swuPVQKRFIRNgJ7p4ABawfz+DieCIAFgATFCro4ZBwOFQ7HCKAjIMjUaB0VicXiIp5XBwUP4qPjQJ4AISCzyk65JJBUIA)):

```
// type Parameters<T extends Function> = T extends (...args: infer R) => any ? R : never;
// How it's implemented, Parameters is a built-in type.

function someFn(a: string, b?: number, c?: any): any { /* ... */ }

type T0 = Parameters<typeof someFn>; // type T0 = [string, (number | undefined)?, any?]

const x: T0 = ['hello', 42]; // good
const y: T0 = ['hello', 'world', '!!']; // bad
```

Comment: Thanks, I missed the `?` after the `c` param. I knew about the possibility of having an array with the types mirrored within. Unfortunately this is not enough, I also want to fetch the given names, but I assume it's not possible, then?

Comment: @jlang Unless you limit yourself to functions with a single, object argument (`function foo({bar, baz}) {}`), I'm afraid not.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha you can also use the built-in type `Parameters` for that purpose. `type T1 = Parameters<typeof someFn>`